# Accept integers and float no. from command line in java and store them in two diff array for integer and float no.s

Tags: java, command-line-arguments

the problem is how to identify which no. is `integer` and which no. is `float`

all the numbers should be passed by the command line arguments

AND store the `int` numbers in `int[]`  and `float` noumberss in `float[]`

Comment: The main problem is converting from one data type to another...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go by the same rules as your source code, just look for a "." in each parameter and convert those to floats and the rest to ints.

I really don't see where this is going though, are you sure you can't just handle all numbers as floats?

For conversion from string to numeric types, see the respective conversion functions:

- [Integer.parseInt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29)
- [Float.parseFloat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#parseFloat%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: Thanks...this answer have solved my problem..i have used args[i].indexOf('.')